# Completing Tour page before joining a site

Tags: feature-request, badges, tour

If you read Tour page before joining a site you will see the following:

> [image: first badge]

The last paragraph says that I will claim badge “Informed”. It’s wrong. Joining the site after reading the page doesn’t give you a badge. You need to “read” it again to get such badge.

> [image: earn it again]

More over the first badge could be “Autobiographer” actually if you already have completed “about” in your profile for previous site.

> [image: real first]

Comment: The page doesn't say you will receive it after joining. It says you're allowed to receive it after joining.

Comment: @animuson it looks weird. No badge could be earned **before** joining.

Comment: You can't do either of the other two bullet points before joining either. It's just a list of things you can do when you join. I don't see how it's weird at all.

Comment: @animuson it’s weird because I need to do the same thing twice (read the Tour) for earning the badge. It would be fair to give an “Informed” badge if you make a join from the Tour page.

Comment: It actually says "Joining allows you too...Claim your fist badge" this means you have to actually join before you can claim your first badge.